# Heap is Increasing

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, heap-memory

My Code Is consuming alot of memory and increasing heap continusely till a certain size , why is it consuming so much memory im closing out object too. However when i use the garbage collector it works fine and releases the memory. the memory graph should be balanced.
[Visual Vm showing heap consumption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrjzv.png)

```
while (true) {
            File downloadedFile = new File("C:/Users/HP/Downloads/mynewfile.xml");
            File file = new File("C:/Users/HP/Downloads/myfile.xml");
            downloadedFile.createNewFile();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(downloadedFile);
            if (false) {
                if (!checksum(MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"), file).
                        equalsIgnoreCase(checksum(MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"), downloadedFile))) {
                    throw new Exception("size mismatch on edms");
                } else {
                    if (downloadedFile.exists()) downloadedFile.delete();
                }
            }
            out.close();
            downloadedFile.delete();


        }
```

Comment: That screenshot in itself is not proof of a memory leak. Just because one GC doesn't collect to the same target as a previous one doesn't necessarily mean anything (different GC-kinds can be run, for example). So unless you actually run out of memory with this (do-nothing) code, I wouldn't assume you have a memory leak. Also: there's almost ever a need to call `createNewFile`: a new `FileOutputStream` will by default create the file if it doesn't exist.